# Is this possible in javascript (without using jquery) make tab key of keyboard enable or disable under if-else conditions?

Tags: javascript

i have a condition like below (make tab key of keyboard enable or disable under if-else conditions):-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById('firstbutton').style.visibility=='block')
{
//keyboard tab key for disable
alert('testing disable');
}
if(document.getElementById('firstbutton').style.visibility=='none')
{
//keyboard tab key for enable
alert('testing enable');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't disable keys, you can only bind a key event listener and ignore specific keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 9)
    return false; // Disable Tab!
}
```

Comment: if i write above code under visibility=='block' will it disable tab key till its visibility is equal to block?

Comment: This has to be written in the `focus` event of the `span`.

Comment: should i first create a span?

Comment: Sorry... The Div.. not the span or whatever, but I was referrig to the `firstbutton`.

Comment: Yeah, the event has to be triggered. Right?

Comment: u only disabled tab what about enabling(leave it i know that)